# Problems with std::put_time()

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, c++-chrono

Hi I have a very simple test case here that compiles under visual studio 2012.  However it produces a run time failure.  The line that produces this failure is copied exactly like they have it on cppreference.com in LOTS of examples related to time functionality.
Page with example just like this http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/localtime

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

ofstream & GetTimeStr(ofstream & ofs)
    {
    time_t rawTime = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());

    // fails on this line, very deep inside the runtime code.
    ofs << std::put_time(std::localtime(&rawTime), "%c %Z");
    return ofs;
    }

int main()
    {
    std::ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open("Logger.txt");

    if (ofs.good())
        {
        ofs << "some text " << GetTimeStr(ofs) << " more text ";   
        }
    }
```

To keep this post clean I put the stack trace here
http://ideone.com/WaeQcf

Comment: Can you provide some more details about how it fails, e.g. error messages, exceptions, a stack trace?

Comment: The error is a window popup it says    Microsoft Visual Studio C Runtime Library has detected a fatal error in ConsoleApplication6.exe.



Press Break to debug the program or Continue to terminate the program.

Comment: Added link to stack trace in post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that this is a bug in the VC runtime that's being triggered by the use of `%Z` in `strftime` (which is called by `std::put_time`):

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/759720/vs2012-strftime-crash-with-z-formatting-code

Unfortunately it doesn't look like it's a high priority bug for Microsoft.

Comment: Ok, thanks, it works without the %Z, my project can do without the zone information.